# How can I parse a pubDate from a RSS feed to a Date object in java

Tags: java, rss

How can I parse a pubDate from a RSS feed to a Date object in java.
The format is: Thu, 03 Mar 2016 15:30:00 +0200

I tried to do it by this:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        //java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
        java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
        try {
            utilDate = formatter.parse(date);
        }
        catch (java.text.ParseException p1)
        {
            p1.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

but the java.sql.Date  only save the date without the time
for example: "2016-02-06 00:00:00"

Comment: *"but the java.sql.Date only save the date without the time..."* Are you sure? `utilDate.getTime()` returns `long` with value of time since the start date of calendar till now. How can it not return time? You can use `getTimestamp(...)` method of `java.sql.Date` to convert it back to `java.util.Date` and return the date with time.

Answer (score 1):

[java.sql.Date](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/sql/Date.java) doesn't have Time

You should probably use [java.sql.Timestamp](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/sql/Timestamp.java#Timestamp)

You can use it like this

```
new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: @user3346907 You can mark this as answer by clicking the right mark beside answer, if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

## RFC 1123

That format of your input string happens to be defined as a standard, [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123).

That format has long been outmoded by the much more sensible formats defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). If possible I strongly suggest migrating.

## java.time

You are using old date-time classes that have been outmoded by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later.

Your input’s format happens to be predefined as a constant in java.time. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "Thu, 03 Mar 2016 15:30:00 +0200";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , formatter );
```

Someday the JDBC drivers will be updated to use the java.time types directly. Until then convert to the java.sql types, specifically [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) in our case here. To convert we need an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC. We can extract one from our `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant();
java.sql.Timestamp ts = java.sql.Timestamp.from( instant );
```